# Exposing Spotify's "Did you mean" feature via web api

Tags: spotify

I'm writing a website that uses Spotify's web api to search for music. A common issue is people don't always know the correct spelling of a track title or an artist's name.

For example if I search for *Danza Kaduro* using the webapi:

```
http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q=artist:danza+kaduro
```

The response is:

```
{"info": {"num_results": 0, "limit": 100, "offset": 0, "query": "artist:danza kaduro", "type": "track", "page": 1}, "tracks": []}
```

But in my desktop Spotify it auto-corrects, and on android has a **DID YOU MEAN?** suggestion of the correct spelling "*Danza Kuduro*".

Is this available to third parties? Is there another service that could be used to correct the spelling of artists **or** tracks when zero results are returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is not available to third parties. It is mostly a technical reason. It just has not been implemented and it is unlikely to be in the near future. (yes, I work for Spotify)

Other services that could be used for this could is just google. If you don't get a result from spotify search, ask google, if google suggest something else, search for that in Spotify.

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

Check spelling.correctedQuery on:

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/cse/list

Echonest has a more proper artist database and also a fuzzy_match query parameter that seems to suggest this would help, but I couldn't make it find Danza Kuduro by searching for danza kaduro.

http://developer.echonest.com/docs/v4/artist.html#search